# How to read content inside [RoutePrefix("content")]

Tags: c#, routes, webapi2

Is possible to read Route Prefix value in C# web api controller. I tried out, but I couldn't find any way to access this.

`[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]`

How to get the value inside `""` in to a variable.

Comment: Assuming you are inside controller: `this.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<RoutePrefixAttribute>().Prefix;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RoutePrefix` is regular .NET attribute, so you can reach it like this (assuming you are doing that from inside of controller):

```
// this.GetType() is type of current controller
var prefix = this.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<RoutePrefixAttribute>().Prefix;
```